# ReactJs input element content does not change

Tags: reactjs, events, onchange

Refer to the code below, no matter what I type in the input element, its value doesn't change.
Seems the input element become readonly.
However, the onChange event do fire and the console log output always display the initial value.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

**Combo.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface ComboProps { label:string, value:string }

// 'HelloProps' describes the shape of props.
// State is never set so we use the 'undefined' type.
export class Combo extends React.Component<ComboProps, ComboProps> {
    constructor(props:any){
        super(props);
        this.state = {label:this.props.label, value: this.props.value};
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    }
    update(event:any){
        console.log(this.state.value);
    }
    render() {
        return <div className="wo-boundary">
            <div  className="wo-label" ref="label">{this.state.label}</div>
            <div  className="wo-widget wo-input-module wo-combo">
                <input ref="box" type="text" onChange={this.update} value={this.state.value} />
                <div ref="toggle"  className="toggle">
                    <svg  className="icon-dropdown-toggle">
                        <use href="svg-symbols.svg#icon-dropdown-toggle"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: I the "any" type annotation really bringing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the state in the `update` callback:

```
update(event){
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}
```